# mergind two dataframe according to intervals in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two df such as

**df1**

```
          Name  start1  end1
0  OK0100087.1     187   250
1  OK0100087.1     752   830
2  OK0100087.1     380   689
```

**df2**

```
            Name  start2  end2
0  OK0100087.1_0  0       375
1  OK0100087.1_1  376     750
2  OK0100087.1_3  751     1000
```

and I would like to merge the two df and get :

```
          Name  start1  end1 start2 end2 Name2
0  OK0100087.1     187   250  0     375  OK0100087.1_0
1  OK0100087.1     750   830  751   1000 OK0100087.1_3
2  OK0100087.1     380   689  752   830  OK0100087.1_3
```

so the idea is that I check for each start1-end1 value in wich interval start2-end2 it falls for instance;

```
          Name  start1  end1 start2 end2 Name2
0  OK0100087.1     187   250
1  OK0100087.1     752   830
2  OK0100087.1     380   689
```

row0:
`187-250` is between `[0-375]` so I add this df2 line

```
          Name  start1  end1 start2 end2 Name2
0  OK0100087.1     187   250 0      375  OK0100087.1_0
1  OK0100087.1     752   830
2  OK0100087.1     380   689
```

row1:
`752-830` is between `[751-1000]`so I add this df2 line

```
          Name  start1  end1 start2 end2 Name2
0  OK0100087.1     187   250  0     375  OK0100087.1_0
1  OK0100087.1     750   830  751   1000 OK0100087.1_3
2  OK0100087.1     380   689
```

row2:
`380-689` is between `[376-750]`so I add this df2 line

```
          Name  start1  end1 start2 end2 Name2
0  OK0100087.1     187   250  0     375  OK0100087.1_0
1  OK0100087.1     750   830  751   1000 OK0100087.1_3
2  OK0100087.1     380   689  752   830  OK0100087.1_3
```

Comment: Use solution from dupe answers, if something not working for you let me know. Cross join is better if not huge data, else memory consuming. Iterate method working with any data, but slowier

Comment: Well I know how to merge two dataframe but here the difficulty is that it needs to merge depending on interval values given by two columns (start2 and end2) and I do not know how to deal with that...

Comment: Unfortuantely need cross join and then filtering or loop solution

Comment: But how to cross join since Name in df1 and df2 are not exactly the same ?

Comment: cross join means need helper column tmp and join by it.

Comment: Ok I found a solution yhank you @jezrael